# How do I hide a row in a WPF grid?

Tags: wpf, grid

I have been hiding a row in a WPF grid by setting the `Height` property to 0.

I was expecting something akin to a `Visible` property.

Is there a more appropriate way to hide the row?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could set the visibility of the row's content to "Collapsed".  This will only work if the Height property of the RowDefinition is set to "Auto" so the row sizes based on it's content.

For example,

```
<Grid>  
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red"><TextBlock>Visible Row</TextBlock></Border>
  <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Visibility="Collapsed"><TextBlock>Hidden Row</TextBlock></Border>
  <Border Grid.Row="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red"><TextBlock>Visible Row</TextBlock></Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: How would you do if you have multiple columns? It's not very practical to hide each element...

Comment: Clement- Wrap each element in the row in a container such as another grid, and simply show/hide/collapse the visibility of the container.

Comment: I used it for column, great!

Answer (score 3):

I actually just asked the same question a couple of days ago, take a look here:

[Hide grid row in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502178/wpf-hide-grid-row)

Basically setting the RowHeight to Auto and then Setting the Visibility="Collapsed" will hide the row for you. The only issue I had was the Margins, but that was minor. At least the row got hidden.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this :

XAML :

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*" x:Name="name1" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="name2" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

C# for collapse :

```
name1.Height = new GridLength(0);
name2.Height = new GridLength(0);
```

C# for visibility:

```
name1.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
name2.Height = GridLength.Auto;
```