# Dynamically toggle visibility of WPF grid column from C# code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, visibility

My problem is: I can't find out how to toggle the visibility of my WPF grid column. Assume following XAML markup:

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="Row1" />
        <RowDefinition x:Name="Row2" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column1" />
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column2" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Aferwards the grid is filled with some controls etc. Now I want to hide a single column dynamically out of my C# code. I've tried achieving this by setting the the column's definition width to zero, e.g. `Column1.Width = 0`. This works, but I don't really like this solution - is there really no better way?

I'm looking for something like `myGrid.Columns[0].Visibility = COLLAPSED` or `Column1.Visibility = HIDDEN`. I just can't find something like that - any ideas?

Comment: @DaveRook It will do it, of course - I'm just curious if there's an easy method without such a hack

Comment: What do you expect to happen to the controls in that column?

Comment: @DaveRook When collapsing the column I want to collapse all the controls contained, too - so the whole column including content should be invisible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide grid row in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502178/hide-grid-row-in-wpf)

Answer (score 45):

```
<ColumnDefinition>
  <ColumnDefinition.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ColumnDefinition">
      <Setter Property="Width" Value="*" />
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsColumnVisible}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ColumnDefinition.Style>
</ColumnDefinition>
```

Please do implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel

Comment: This is the way to go if you want dynamic visbility of the column.

Comment: @Lennart Agreed. This should be the accepted solution.

Comment: Simple and clean. I agree that this should be the accepted answer as it offers a decent amount of flixibilty and allows the user to stick to MVVM.

Comment: I'm new to WPF, should I apply this to all the column definitions ? Because each of my column has it's own Width. So what should I be doing ?

Comment: @Harxish you can if you want too.  However,  will it not affect the user experience if you have too many columns?. Users will have to cope with horizontal scrolling .

Answer (score 14):

The simplest way to do this is to add a named `Grid` as the top level control in the relevant column that you want to hide. Then you can just hide it and all of its contents as you would any other control:

In XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="Row1" />
        <RowDefinition x:Name="Row2" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column1" />
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column2" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="GridColumn1" Grid.Column="1">
        ...
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Then in code behind:

```
GridColumn1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

As you have more than one row in your `Grid`, you may want to rearrange them like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column1" />
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column2" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="GridColumn0" Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="GridColumn1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

UPDATE >>>

It is not really necessary to rearrange the main `Grid` like this... you *could* just as easily add two `Grid` controls, one in each row of the relevant column and then set the `Visibility` of them both together:

```
InnerGrid1.Visibility = InnerGrid2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

You could even add a `Grid` into each cell of the main `Grid` and have full control over which cells are visible at any one time.

Comment: yeah, I think I'll have to rearrange the XAML code to achieve what I want how I want - although this is something i tried to avoid, because it's a lot of code from some colleagues..thanks anyway :)

Comment: even though you get in trouble if you want to hide a column AND a row simultaneously

Comment: Collapsing all elements in a row/column only collapses the row/column if its height/width is set to "Auto". Look at: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/437237/wpf-grid-column-and-row-hiding if you want to collapse.

Answer (score 7):

In [WPF Grid Column and Row Hiding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437237/WPF-Grid-Column-and-Row-Hiding) on Code Project, they show a way using dependency properties. They set `Visible = false`, but internally, it sets `Width = 0`.

Another idea is to delete the column definition in code behind... But I guess it's an even worse hack! :(

Comment: I tried deleting the column definition itself: the grid got rearranged correctly, but the column's content was still there (elements were overlapping)..but thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

An ugly hack would be to just change the width to 0 (out of sight, out of mind).

There are many reasons why you shouldn't do this but, based upon your situation, it may suffice!

Comment: Will you please share some of the reasons why just setting height to zero is a bad idea?

Comment: If the row is re-sizable, you may want to save and restore that size, but 0 height will do meanwhile

Answer (score -11):

Use following to Hide the grid. Similarly you can hide the row definitions and column definitions using Name property.

myGrid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;

Comment: Just one column needs to be hidden not the whole grid.