# How to sort gridview column by cell colour?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I have a gridview in my visual studio 2015 master page web project. I am populating the gridview in codebehind via Datatable. And Datatable have 4 columns and one column is Status (displaying colours RED, ORANGE and GREEN) depending on data for that field.

I have set timer every 30 seconds to refresh the gridview (code behind - Data load function). I want the column to be sorted by colour on status = RED ASC (Red at the top).

I am trying to figure out way to achieve the idea

My aspx page code is below

```html
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <asp:Timer ID="ctlTimer" runat="server" Interval="30000" OnTick="OnTimerIntervalElapse">
  </asp:Timer>
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblTimer" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="pnlUpdate" EnableViewState="False">
    <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ctlTimer" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" Width="100%" AllowSorting="True"></asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>​
```

My code-Behind code.

```
     // create data table
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // create columns
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Status", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col3", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("col4", typeof(string)));

        //  get list of items to display
        getListofSystems(1);

        // clear datatable
        dt.Clear();
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var statusValue = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Status"));
            if (statusValue == "Red")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = Color.FromName("Red");
            }
            if (statusValue == "Orange")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = Color.FromName("Orange");
            }
            if (statusValue == "Green")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = Color.FromName("Green");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnTimerIntervalElapse(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getListofSystems(1);
    }
```

Load data as a code/logic below.

```
 DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

 // display system name
 dr["col1"] = ID;

// Get status from database
 switch (status)
 {
     case "red":
         dr["Status"] = "Red";
         break;
     case "orange":
         dr["Status"] = "Orange";
         break;
     case "green":
         dr["Status"] = "Green";
         break;
 }
 dr["col3"] = Datetime.Now;
 dr["col4"] = contact;

 // add row to datatable
 dt.Rows.Add(dr);

 // bind data to gridview
 GridView1.Visible = true;
 GridView1.DataSource = dt;
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

This is pretty much all the code. I have removed un-necessary code to populate the data rows from above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a column StatusWeight with an int datatype

```
// Get status from database
 switch (status)
 {
     case "red":
         dr["Status"] = "Red";
         dr["StatusWeight"] = 1;
         break;
     case "orange":
         dr["Status"] = "Orange";
         dr["StatusWeight"] = 2;
         break;
     case "green":
         dr["Status"] = "Green";
         dr["StatusWeight"] = 3;
         break;
 }
```

Then sort by the StatusWeight column

Comment: Cant add any more columns. Is there any other way of doing it? Do you think I can some how hide this column and still use sorting on it?

Comment: yes you can make StatusWeight a hidden column and still sort it. Just sort it in the query or datatable before you bind..

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383893(v=vs.90).aspx

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107916/sorting-rows-in-a-data-table

Comment: both the links are for datagridview the are not working. they are obsolete.

Comment: my bad, you are using wpf. 

The first link you can replace with

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227091/dynamically-toggle-visibility-of-wpf-grid-column-from-c-sharp-code

the accepted answer of the second link has nothing to do with datagrids at all

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091457/how-to-hide-columns-in-an-asp-net-gridview-with-auto-generated-columns

Comment: Worked by also adding StatusWeight to GridView1_RowDataBound and if (statusValue == "1") ...