# wpf toggling visibility collapse only works once

Tags: wpf, binding, visibility, datatrigger

What i want to do is collapse the bottom section of the WPF ui based on the checkbox toggle. This mostly works as expected so far. Below as you step through the images you'll see the collapse stops working once the grid splitter is moved. I do not understand why or how to fix this.

Start of the application, appears correct.

[image: Initial opening of the application]

Toggle the checkbox and the botttom section disappears as expected.

[image]

Toggle the checkbox once more and then move the splitter vertically, everything appears as expected.

[image]

Now toggle the checkbox one last time and you'll notice the top section doesn't fill the application like it once did before. This is where it appears broken! I would expect the yellow section to fill the UI like it did in the initial toggle.

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="525"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <CheckBox Name="ToggleVisibility" Margin="10" IsChecked="True" Content="Toggle Bottom Section"></CheckBox>

        <StackPanel Background="#feca00" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock FontSize="20" Foreground="#58290A">Top Section</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="2" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <GridSplitter.Style>
                <Style TargetType="GridSplitter">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ToggleVisibility, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </GridSplitter.Style>
        </GridSplitter>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Background="LightBlue">
            <StackPanel.Style>
                <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ToggleVisibility, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Style>

            <TextBlock FontSize="20" Foreground="black">Bottom Section</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this happens is that when you move the splitter it overwrites the `Height` property of the last `RowDefinition` and sets it to actual height of whatever is presented in the according row of the `Grid` - the second `StackPanel` (bottom section) in your case. It no longer is set to `Auto`, so even if you collapse the bottom section the row maintains it's height - hence the empty space.

I sometimes find myself in a similar situation, and what I do then is to span the control, which I want to take up all the space, across the remaining rows using `Grid.RowSpan` attached property. In your case you could achieve it by applying the following style to your first `StackPanel` (top section):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ToggleVisibility}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="3" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then the `StackPanel` will span to the bottom of the `Grid` regardless of the following rows' heights.

**EDIT**

Since you're not satisfied with spanning the control, here's another solution: derive from `RowDefinition` class and wire your own visibility logic. Here's an example:

```
public class MyRowDefinition : RowDefinition
{
    static MyRowDefinition()
    {
        HeightProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(MyRowDefinition),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
            {
                CoerceValueCallback = CoerceHeightPropertyValue
            });
    }

    private static object CoerceHeightPropertyValue(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        if (Equals(d.GetValue(IsVisibleProperty), false))
            return new GridLength(0d);
        else
            return baseValue;
    }

    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsVisibleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsVisibleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "IsVisible",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(MyRowDefinition),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
            {
                DefaultValue = true,
                PropertyChangedCallback = IsVisiblePropertyChanged
            });

    private static void IsVisiblePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        d.InvalidateProperty(RowDefinition.HeightProperty);
    }
}
```

Then use that class instead of `RowDefinition` in your grid and bind the `IsVisible` property to the check state of the checkbox.

Comment: would there be a way to just reset the Grid.Row Height to be the maximum it can be rather than the rowspan?

Comment: You could set the `RowDefinition.Height` property using style and use a similar trigger to set it to `0` when the checkbox is unchecked, but it looks like the splitter is setting the height using local value, which precedes values set in styles, so it would "break" anyway. See [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms743230(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: yeah i actually just attempted that and it doesn't work. seems like a logical solution but breaks

Comment: is there a way to get the height of the available content area and just set the height to that for the row

Comment: thanks for the solution, its great to see both options as solutions

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `StackPanel` and the `GridSplitter` are collapsed, but that `Grid.Row` 3 is not. I'm not sure why the Auto height does no close it out. EDIT: I see that @Grx70 has explained it.

This: [Hide grid row in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502178/wpf-hide-grid-row)
suggests that setting all children to `Visibility.Collapsed` ought to work, but you have the option of setting the height of Grid.Row 3 to 0.

I think the Height="5" of your `GridSplitter` might also keep it taking up space, taking precedence over the style setting (it is collapsed and gets Height 0 from that, but gets Height 5 from the Height="5", which wins (but it is still invisible). It might be better to but that in the style too:

```
 <Setter Property="Height" Value="5" />
```