# Collapse Grid Row in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger, wpf-grid

I have created a custom WPF element extended from `RowDefinition` that should collapse rows in a grid when the `Collapsed` property of the element is set to `True`.

It does it by using a converter and a datatrigger in a style to set the height of the row to 0. It is based on this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31984499/4601149).

In the example below, this works perfectly when the grid splitter is over half way up the window. However, when it is less than half way, the rows still collapse, but the first row does not expand. Instead, there is just a white gap where the rows used to be. This can be seen in the image below.

[image: Picture shows under half, the bottom row doesn't disappear, but over half it does]

Similarly, if `MinHeight` or `MaxHeight` is set on any of the rows that are collapsed, it no longer collapses the row at all. I tried to fix this by adding setters for these properties in the data trigger but it did not fix it.

My question is what can be done differently so that it does not matter about the size of the rows or if `MinHeight` / `MaxHeight` are set, it is just able to collapse the rows?

---

MCVE

*MainWindow.xaml.cs*

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace RowCollapsibleMCVE
{
    public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private bool isCollapsed;

        public bool IsCollapsed
        {
            get => isCollapsed;
            set
            {
                isCollapsed = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public class CollapsibleRow : RowDefinition
    {
        #region Default Values
        private const bool COLLAPSED_DEFAULT = false;
        private const bool INVERT_COLLAPSED_DEFAULT = false;
        #endregion

        #region Dependency Properties
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CollapsedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Collapsed", typeof(bool), typeof(CollapsibleRow), new PropertyMetadata(COLLAPSED_DEFAULT));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty InvertCollapsedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("InvertCollapsed", typeof(bool), typeof(CollapsibleRow), new PropertyMetadata(INVERT_COLLAPSED_DEFAULT));
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public bool Collapsed {
            get => (bool)GetValue(CollapsedProperty);
            set => SetValue(CollapsedProperty, value);
        }

        public bool InvertCollapsed {
            get => (bool)GetValue(InvertCollapsedProperty);
            set => SetValue(InvertCollapsedProperty, value);
        }
        #endregion
    }

    public class BoolVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values.Length > 0 && values[0] is bool collapsed)
            {
                if (values.Length > 1 && values[1] is bool invert && invert)
                {
                    collapsed = !collapsed;
                }

                return collapsed ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
            }

            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window x:Class="RowCollapsibleMCVE.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RowCollapsibleMCVE"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Visibility x:Key="CollapsedVisibilityVal">Collapsed</Visibility>
        <local:BoolVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolVisibilityConverter"/>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CollapsibleRow}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="{StaticResource CollapsedVisibilityVal}">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="Collapsed"
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                            <Binding Path="InvertCollapsed"
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="0"/>
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Content="Collapse Row"
                  IsChecked="{Binding IsCollapsed}"/>
        <Grid Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <local:CollapsibleRow Height="3*" />
                <local:CollapsibleRow Height="Auto" />
                <local:CollapsibleRow Collapsed="{Binding IsCollapsed}" Height="*" /> <!-- Using [MaxHeight="300"] breaks this completely -->
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Background="Red"/>

            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1"
                          Height="10"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <GridSplitter.Visibility>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}" >
                        <Binding Path="IsCollapsed"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </GridSplitter.Visibility>
            </GridSplitter>

            <StackPanel Background="Blue"
                        Grid.Row="2">
                <StackPanel.Visibility>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}" >
                        <Binding Path="IsCollapsed"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </StackPanel.Visibility>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: https://github.com/KBurov/Testing/blob/master/Common/Extended/RowDefinitionExtended.cs

Comment: @ASh Thank you for comment. It is really useful and appears to have been integrated into Funk's answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need is something to cache the height(s) of the visible row. After that, you no longer need converters or to toggle visibility of contained controls.

**CollapsibleRow**

```
public class CollapsibleRow : RowDefinition
{
    #region Fields
    private GridLength cachedHeight;
    private double cachedMinHeight;
    #endregion

    #region Dependency Properties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CollapsedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Collapsed", typeof(bool), typeof(CollapsibleRow), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnCollapsedChanged));

    private static void OnCollapsedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(d is CollapsibleRow row && e.NewValue is bool collapsed)
        {
            if(collapsed)
            {
                if(row.MinHeight != 0)
                {
                    row.cachedMinHeight = row.MinHeight;
                    row.MinHeight = 0;
                }
                row.cachedHeight = row.Height;
            }
            else if(row.cachedMinHeight != 0)
            {
                row.MinHeight = row.cachedMinHeight;
            }
            row.Height = collapsed ? new GridLength(0) : row.cachedHeight;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public bool Collapsed
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(CollapsedProperty);
        set => SetValue(CollapsedProperty, value);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="RowCollapsibleMCVE.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RowCollapsibleMCVE"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Content="Collapse Row"
                  IsChecked="{Binding IsCollapsed}"/>
        <Grid Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <local:CollapsibleRow Height="3*" MinHeight="0.0001"/>
                <local:CollapsibleRow Collapsed="{Binding IsCollapsed}" Height="Auto" />
                <local:CollapsibleRow Collapsed="{Binding IsCollapsed}" Height="*" /> <!-- Using [MinHeight="50" MaxHeight="100"] behaves as expected -->
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Background="Red"/>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <StackPanel Background="Blue" Grid.Row="2" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You should have either a `MaxHeight` on the collapsable row (the third one in our example) or a `MinHeight` on the non-collapsable row (the first) adjacent to the splitter. This to ensure the star sized row has a size when you put the splitter all the way up and toggle visibility. Only then it will be able to take over the remaining space.

---

**UPDATE**

As @Ivan mentioned in his post, the controls that are contained by collapsed rows will still be focusable, allowing users to access them when they shouldn't.
Admittedly, it could be a pain setting the visibility for all controls by hand, especially for large XAMLs. So let's add some custom behavior to sync the collapsed rows with their controls.

1. The Problem

First, run the example using the code above, then collapse the bottom rows by checking the checkbox. Now, press the TAB key once and use the ARROW UP key to move the `GridSplitter`. As you can see, even though the splitter isn't visible, the user can still access it.

2. The Fix

Add a new file `Extensions.cs` to host the behavior.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using RowCollapsibleMCVE;

namespace Extensions
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(bool))]
    public class BooleanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return !(bool)value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }
    }

    public class GridHelper : DependencyObject
    {
        #region Attached Property

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SyncCollapsibleRowsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "SyncCollapsibleRows",
                typeof(Boolean),
                typeof(GridHelper),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false,
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSyncWithCollapsibleRows)
                ));

        public static void SetSyncCollapsibleRows(UIElement element, Boolean value)
        {
            element.SetValue(SyncCollapsibleRowsProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnSyncWithCollapsibleRows(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is Grid grid)
            {
                grid.Loaded += (o,ev) => SetBindingForControlsInCollapsibleRows((Grid)o);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Logic

        private static IEnumerable<UIElement> GetChildrenFromPanels(IEnumerable<UIElement> elements)
        {
            Queue<UIElement> queue = new Queue<UIElement>(elements);
            while (queue.Any())
            {
                var uiElement = queue.Dequeue();
                if (uiElement is Panel panel)
                {
                    foreach (UIElement child in panel.Children) queue.Enqueue(child);
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return uiElement;
                }
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<UIElement> ElementsInRow(Grid grid, int iRow)
        {
            var rowRootElements = grid.Children.OfType<UIElement>().Where(c => Grid.GetRow(c) == iRow);

            if (rowRootElements.Any(e => e is Panel))
            {
                return GetChildrenFromPanels(rowRootElements);
            }
            else
            {
                return rowRootElements;
            }
        }

        private static BooleanConverter MyBooleanConverter = new BooleanConverter();

        private static void SyncUIElementWithRow(UIElement uiElement, CollapsibleRow row)
        {
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(uiElement, UIElement.FocusableProperty, new Binding
            {
                Path = new PropertyPath(CollapsibleRow.CollapsedProperty),
                Source = row,
                Converter = MyBooleanConverter
            });
        }

        private static void SetBindingForControlsInCollapsibleRows(Grid grid)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < grid.RowDefinitions.Count; i++)
            {
                if (grid.RowDefinitions[i] is CollapsibleRow row)
                {
                    ElementsInRow(grid, i).ToList().ForEach(uiElement => SyncUIElementWithRow(uiElement, row));
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

3. More Testing

Change the XAML to add the behavior and some textboxes (which are also focusable).

```
<Window x:Class="RowCollapsibleMCVE.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RowCollapsibleMCVE"
        xmlns:ext="clr-namespace:Extensions"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Content="Collapse Row" IsChecked="{Binding IsCollapsed}"/>
        <!-- Set the desired behavior through an Attached Property -->
        <Grid ext:GridHelper.SyncCollapsibleRows="True" Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="3*" MinHeight="0.0001" />
                <local:CollapsibleRow Collapsed="{Binding IsCollapsed}" Height="Auto" />
                <local:CollapsibleRow Collapsed="{Binding IsCollapsed}" Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Background="Red">
                <TextBox Width="100" Margin="40" />
            </StackPanel>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Background="Blue">
                <TextBox Width="100" Margin="40" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the end:

- The logic is completely hidden from XAML (clean).
- We're still providing flexibility:

  - For each `CollapsibleRow` you could bind `Collapsed` to a different variable.
  - Rows that don't need the behavior can use base `RowDefinition` (apply on demand).

---

**UPDATE 2**

As @Ash pointed out in the comments, you can use [WPF's native caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-callbacks-and-validation#constraints-and-desired-values) to store the height values. Resulting in very clean code with autonomous properties, each handling its own => robust code. For example, using the code below you won't be able to move the `GridSplitter` when rows are collapsed, even without the behavior being applied.

Of course the controls would still be accessible, allowing the user to trigger events. So we'd still need the behavior, but the `CoerceValueCallback` does provide a consistent linkage between the `Collapsed` and the various height dependency properties of our `CollapsibleRow`.

```
public class CollapsibleRow : RowDefinition
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CollapsedProperty;

    public bool Collapsed
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(CollapsedProperty);
        set => SetValue(CollapsedProperty, value);
    }

    static CollapsibleRow()
    {
        CollapsedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Collapsed",
            typeof(bool), typeof(CollapsibleRow), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnCollapsedChanged));

        RowDefinition.HeightProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CollapsibleRow),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star), null, CoerceHeight));

        RowDefinition.MinHeightProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CollapsibleRow),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, null, CoerceHeight));

        RowDefinition.MaxHeightProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CollapsibleRow),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(double.PositiveInfinity, null, CoerceHeight));
    }

    private static object CoerceHeight(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        return (((CollapsibleRow)d).Collapsed) ? (baseValue is GridLength ? new GridLength(0) : 0.0 as object) : baseValue;
    }

    private static void OnCollapsedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        d.CoerceValue(RowDefinition.HeightProperty);
        d.CoerceValue(RowDefinition.MinHeightProperty);
        d.CoerceValue(RowDefinition.MaxHeightProperty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer and the additional code that handles the visibility of the children of the row. This seems to work great and will likely award you the bounty later on in the week

Comment: Glad you like it! Feel free to leave the bounty open till the end, something even better might come along ;)

Answer (score 4):

The sample above is technically wrong.

What it essentially does is that it tries to force the height of the row to be 0, which is not what you want or should do - the problem is that the tab key will go through the controls even if the height is 0, and Narrator will read those controls. Essentially those controls still exist and are completely clickable, functional and accessible just they are not presented on the window, but they can be still accessed in various ways and may affect the work of the application.

Second (and the thing that causes the problems that you describe as you did not describe the problems above though they are essential too and should not be ignored), you have `GridSplitter` and as said it remains functional even if you force its height to 0 (as explained above). `GridSplitter` means that at the end of the day you are not in the control of the layout, but the user.

What should be done instead is that you should use the plain `RowDefinition` and set its height to `Auto` and then set the `Visibility` of the content of the rows to `Collapsed` - of course you may use data binding and the converter.

EDIT: further clarification - in the code above you set the new properties called `Collapsed` and `InvertCollapsed`. Just because they are named like that they don't have any effect on the row being collapsed, they could be as well called Property1 and Property2. They are used in the `DataTrigger` in a fairly strange way - when their value is changed that value is converted to `Visibility` and then if that converted value is `Collapsed` the setters that force row height to be 0 are called. So someone played a lot of scenery to make it look like that he is collapsing something, but he does not, he only changes the height which is quite different thing to do. And that's where the problems originate from. I certainly suggest to avoid whole this approach, but if you find it is good for your application the minimal thing you need to do is to avoid that approach for the second row where GridSplitter is set up as if you don't your request becomes impossible.

Comment: Hi Ivan, normally when I use this, the components visibility are set to collapsed using the same bound bool and convertor, I will update the question to show this. As for the Auto suggestion, this would not be ideal as for in my current program I am looking for a way where when the screen is initialized, the bottom section takes up roughly a quarter of available space and then the user can manipulate the size of this / collapse it. Hence why I used the MCVE I did in the question

Comment: Hi, I tried to explained that this is not collapsed at all like it would be in other cases and you can check if you add controls and use the tab key as suggested.

The critical part is to set the GridSplitter Visibility to Collapsed instead of its row, that will make it work for you even if you use the same code for the rest of the app. However the problems that I described caused by your approach will remain, but if you are fine with them then you can use that.

Comment: @Dan I updated with further clarification as I can see it wasn't clear to you and then I guess it isn't clear to some other people too and the answer is correct.

Comment: @Ivan Well spotted +1. However, for large XAMLs it can be quite the pain setting the visibility for all controls by hand. I Added behavior to deal with the controls drawing focus.

Comment: @Funk that's where data binding comes to so that you can change everything with one line of code... Now Dan says he can't do that for the reason that probably can't be understood from one comment, but then he can do that only on 1 line manually and keep this faulty approach for the rest...

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for the answer. I do not think you understood my comment, normally I do also set the grid splitter to collapsed and I updated the question to show this. I even removed the collapsed from the row as you  were right about the auto handling the size of that row. Similarly, I set the stack panel to collapse as well in the question. None the less, if the grid splitter is removed from the code, and just the two stack panels are left, the problem still occurs

Comment: @Dan, I don't think that you do that with GridSplitter. If you look carefully you are binding to IsCollapsed which doesn't exist on GridSplitter, so it does nothing.

Comment: Hi Ivan. You are correct, it does not exist on `GridSplitter` but it does exist as a property in the `DataContext` of the program which is what I have bound to. If you try the code, you will see it manipulates the visibility of the `GridSplitter` as expected